# WebCamera (Image Box) Freezes when using Thread.Sleep

Tags: c#

I'm making a program for my camera to take pictures and save them in hidden Images for later use, the camera works fine at the start but when  use the code:

```
    private void mainWinForm_PreviewKeyDown_1(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space)
        {
            //1st Photo
            label1.Text = "3 (Get ready!)";
            label1.Refresh();
            Thread.Sleep(1500);

            label1.Text = "2 (To smile! :) )";
            label1.Refresh();
            Thread.Sleep(1500);

            label1.Text = "1 (Cheeese!)";
            label1.Refresh();
            Thread.Sleep(1500);

            label1.Text = "Taken!";
            label1.Refresh();
            Thread.Sleep(1500);
            imgCapture.Image = imgVideo.Image;
```

The imgVideo.Image will freeze, how do I make this work?

Comment: thread.sleep is bad practice generally speaking. you shouldn't need to do this. it, as you know, puts the whole working of the thread to sleep thus can have knock on effects elsewhere. how do you know imgVideo.Image will freeze? all you are doing is assigning the object to another object. what are you using to represent the imgVideo object? Where does this come from?

Comment: How else could I make it countdown and take the picture?

Comment: pretty simple - use the timer and a counter to see how many times it has executed before finally disabling the timer.

Comment: I use a WebCamera reference and the imgVideo.Image shows what my camera can see

Answer (score 3):

You should not use Thread.Sleep in UI thread, because it makes the main thread sleep and UI unresponsive. Use timer. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx) is excellent comparison of timers in .net. You need `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` for your task, because it also executes in UI thread and you will not have issues setting properties and calling methods of controls.